# text-indent alternative for text inputs in IE 7/8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, cross-browser, internet-explorer-7

Here's my jsFiddle example:

http://jsfiddle.net/jsplashindia/LYUA5/1/

Here's my HTML and CSS:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type='text/css'>
    .testStyle {
    text-indent:30px;            
}
</style>

</head>
<body>

    <input type="text" class="testStyle">

</body>
</html>
```

Basically I need to get an indent for the text in my text input like this:

[image: This is the expected behaviour]

However, in IE 7 and IE 8, I get the following behaviour:

[image: observed behaviour in IE7/8]

I need to get rid of the leading space for the text input field. Is there an alternative to using text-indext so that I'll get the expected behaviour in IE7/8 and in all other browsers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `float:left`

```
.testStyle {
    text-indent:30px;
    float:left      
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/LYUA5/2/)**

***Or***

Use `padding-left`

**[DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/LYUA5/3/)**